# Converse to the Koebe Distortion?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a univalent function on the disk satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$, Koebe Distortion theorem says that

\begin{equation}
\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}\le \left|z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right|\le \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}.
\end{equation}

I'm wondering if there is some kind of a converse statement:

Given a holomorphic function on the unit disk with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0)=1$ satisfying the inequality above, what are some minimal set of conditions that would make $f$ univalent?

I will be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction in terms of finding appropriate references.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is something in this direction http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?rid=comahe-002:1978:53::705&id=browse&id2=browse5&id3=1  Note the typo in the main theorem: It should read $\sinh^2\rho$ instead of $\sinh \rho$.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize you wrote the paper yourself! Thank you for the link :)